# One side of 2015 VW passat gets cold air and the other side hot

Tags: vw, ac, passat

Good day,

I have a 2015 VW Passat. TSI engine 1.8.

In the defrost duct on the instrument panel flap adjust motor is down in the 
open position. This is causing frost on the outside of the windshield.

We opened the panel to see if we can some how mechanically close the flap.
Failed. Assembled the panel back. now I get hot...very hot  Air on the drivers side & Defrost duct and cold air on the passenger side.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: If you have scan tool software that allows you to perform a recalibration give it a try.

Comment: What settings do you have the blowers set too?  specifically, which set of vents is selected, is the AC on or off, and is the temperature set to low or high?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, adapt the Passat B7 climate control dampers.
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Adaptation+climatronic+Passat+B7

Comment: It has been three years and change since they asked, and because outside links often go away, is there a way you can answer the users's question without the link?